# How to adjust positioning of sprites with texture pack

Tags: phaser-framework, sprite-sheet, texturepacker

I'm using texture pack to create a spritesheet and I'm getting this:
[image]

How do I re-position the second sprite so it's in line in the first one. Right now the animation will move the character as well whereas I just want it to raise the man's hand:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your sprites should be aligned before importing them. You can do this in Photoshop or Gimp or any other paint tool.

If that does not work you can use TexturePacker's pivot point editor - but this also requires a framework supporting it. E.g. Phaser 3. (Phaser 2 does not work).

Make sure to use the Phaser 3 exporter, the pivot point editor is in the toolbar ("Edit Pivot points").

Please the pivot point in the same position in your sprites - e.g. the center of the shadow ellipse.

You can watch the changes in real time in the animation editor.

Comment: Your last sentence is incomplete. :)